# Is there a glossary of Word .docx XML tags?

Tags: xml, docx, glossary

I'm trying to create a parser to find the tracked changes and author of a Word `.docx` file...

I found the `document.xml` but there are so many tags! Is there a glossary somewhere to what all those tags stand for?

I'd like to avoid brute forcing my way through this if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"w:ins" denotes what was inserted when trackedchanges are enabled.
"w:del" denotes what was deleted when  trackedchanges are enabled.
"w:commentRangeStart" denotes the start of a comment
"w:commentRangeEnd" denotes the end of the comment.

All text are found inside 
"w:t" tags.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can start gathering information about it in the [Stack Overflow docx tag wiki itself](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/docx/info) .

`.docx` files (as well as other new MS Office files like `.xlsx`) [use OOXML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)

---

In particular :

> Microsoft Office Open XML WordProcessingML is mostly standardized in
>   ECMA 376 and ISO 29500.

You can get the relevant ECMA standard specification here : http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/TC45_available_docs.htm

The specific document you are probably looking for is probably the [Open Office XML, Part 4 : Markup Language Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.pdf)

But of course... this is huge (5219 pages !)

I strongly recommend to pinpoint the functionalities you want, and have a look at existing open source libraries that already do some of the job you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The "Office Open XML" format and its XML vocabularies are described in detail in http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm .

To give you an idea, the following piece of XSLT *should* extract just the effective result text *without tracked deletions* of a wordprocessingML document, like would be stored under `word/document.xml` in a .docx file (a ZIP archive).

```
<!-- Match and output text spans except when
     appearing in w:delText child content -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="w:t">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="w:delText"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For your application to extract changes instead, you'd also have to take care of `w:ins` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my docx4j webapp, specifically http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html

With that you can click on a tag and it will take you to the corresponding definition in the spec.